# Load view controller to container view smaller than screen size

Tags: ios, swift

I have a container view used for navigation.
It's height is 75% of screen height, and on my main navigation controller I load this container, and to this container I load another controller :

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        controller1  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        controller1.delegate=self


        controller1.view.frame=ContainerView.bounds
        ContainerView.addSubview(controller1.view)
        addChildViewController(controller1)
        controller1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

What happens is that **this controller covers all screen, not just 75% of it**, and behind it I see the other container- used as bottom bar, but it should not cover it.

Story board:
[image]

On reality, "container", **covers** the "bar".

Comment: have you set all the auto layout constraints for both container and bar views??

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bC6LTLIT6YgUrynkZyAuPxCv4WeM1Vj3 check sample project

Comment: I set all constrains on storyboard, and I can see on simulator that the colors of the view controller and bar are as expected. But when I load a view controller to it, it stretches all over screen.

Comment: in my code are you talking about ?

Comment: Okay let me show you one more sample Created that is using two container views I think that will solve your problem, Should I post ?

Comment: @Curnelious if you have set autolayout constraints the why  controller1.view.frame=ContainerView.bounds this line of code you are using??? try remove that line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample project created using two container Views

**Two Container Views and Two Different VC to be added in Those Views**

Link - https://github.com/iOS-Geek/ContainerViews.git

**StoryBoard :**

[image]

Expected Output :-

[image]

**Can use as Many Container Views And Subviews Try checking once**

Updated Answer As in your code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        controller1  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        controller1.delegate=self


        controller1.view.frame=ContainerView.bounds
        ContainerView.addSubview(controller1.view)
        addChildViewController(controller1)
        controller1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Everything is fine but here need to add one more property that will Hopefully solve your problem of getting subview out of bounds

need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `true`

So Try using code as

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        controller1  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        controller1.delegate=self


        controller1.view.frame=ContainerView.bounds
        ContainerView.addSubview(controller1.view)
        addChildViewController(controller1)
        controller1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        controller1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: Thanks I found my problem. the thing is that if I want to later load a different view controller into this container, how would I do that ? on storyboard you can connect only a single view controller to a container view.

Comment: For this you can see my code I am adding ViewControllers programmatically not from storyBoard , I am creating weak references there of class that is to be added and then adding it in containerView as subview **Reference in ConstarintsVC.swift** of project available at **Github**

Comment: if any queries in that just comment, will help you, I wrote code in that project to add and remove a subview added in container view

Comment: Wait, when you print self.view.frame.height on your vc1/vc2 , do you get the original full screen size or the new size (which is screen height minus the bar size) ? because i keep getting the original full height of screen and not the new one..

Comment: before adding my Second VC through Code in Container View I am assigning it new frame that is of Container View as shown in expected output, VC to be added is being adjusted to frame size of container view

Comment: me too, still getting the same original height . Anyway thanks a lot.